# Error in middle of SVN update

Tags: svn

I'm encountering a strange error when I do an SVN update on a certain folder. Seems that the folder will only be updated *partially*

```
A    trunk/adw_cleanup
A    trunk/adw_cleanup/lib
A    trunk/adw_cleanup/lib/DriveInfo.pm
A    trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.pl
A    trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.vpw
A    trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.vpj
A    trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.vtg
A    trunk/adw_cleanup/logs
A    trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.vpwhist
svn: warning: Error handling externals definition for 'trunk/adw_cleanup/EDA_Mail':
svn: warning: OPTIONS of 'https://svn05.xxx.yyy.com/rg0501/adw/pcb-gde/EDA_Mail': Could not resolve hostname `svn05.xxx.yyy.com': Host not found (https://svn05.xxx.yyy.com)
svn: warning: Error handling externals definition for 'trunk/adw_cleanup/lib/logfile.pm':
svn: warning: OPTIONS of 'https://svn05.xxx.yyy.com/rg0501/adw/pcb-gde/adw_logfile/trunk/adw_logfile/logfile.pm': Could not resolve hostname `svn05.xxx.yyy.com': Host not found (https://svn05.xxx.yyy.com)
Updated to revision 573.
```

I did an `svn ls -vR`, but there's no listing on `EDA_MAIL` folder.

```
454 houfxxxx              Apr 15  2016 ./
 38 doug.xxx              Jun 18  2013 branches/
103 doug.xxx              Jun 19  2013 tags/
454 houfxxxx              Apr 15  2016 trunk/
454 houfxxxx              Apr 15  2016 trunk/adw_cleanup/
454 houfxxxx         3452 Apr 15  2016 trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.pl
132 doug.xxx         2256 Jun 20  2013 trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.vpj
132 doug.xxx          206 Jun 20  2013 trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.vpw
142 doug.xxx         2134 Jun 20  2013 trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.vpwhist
142 doug.xxx       106496 Jun 20  2013 trunk/adw_cleanup/adw_cleanup.vtg
141 doug.xxx              Jun 20  2013 trunk/adw_cleanup/lib/
132 doug.xxx        17700 Jun 20  2013 trunk/adw_cleanup/lib/DriveInfo.pm
132 doug.xxx              Jun 20  2013 trunk/adw_cleanup/logs/
```

The files `svn05.xxx.yyy.com` is an previous server where which we the repository was migrated from (i.e. code no longer hosted in `svn05.xxx.yyy.com`). Is there a chance it is caused by [SVN keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)? Some of the source files have `HeadURL`?
Also some of the files in `EDA_MAIL` are binary files, but I don't see how binary files can cause problems.

My SVN client is svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486) running under RedHat Linux. I also encounter similar error messages when I update using TortoiseSVN under Windows (SVN 1.8)

How do I fix this problem? I don't have access to the repository server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must upgrade your svn client. SVN 1.6 is very old and is not  supported. Upgrade to the latest 1.9.x build.
2. The problem occurs because there are invalid external definitions (`svn:externals`) in the repository. They are invalid because point to unreachable repository. Fix or remove the externals. For further info about svn externals, read [SVNBook | Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html).